# Does restlet add a user agent header by default?

Tags: restlet

Does the restlet java library add a user-agent header if the developer does not specify one?

If so, what is the value does it use for the header?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The content of the `User-Agent` header is available from the `agent` attribute of the `ClientInfo` class:

```
// Client side
getRequest().getClientInfo().setAgent("something");

// Server side
String userAgent = getRequest().getClientInfo().getAgent();
```

This can be set on the client side and gotten on the server side.

If nothing is specified when sending a request with Restlet. For example, with such code:

```
String url = "http://localhost:8182/contacts/";
ClientResource cr = new ClientResource(url);
cr.get();
```

The content of the header is the following:

```
Jetty/9.2.6.v20141205,Restlet-Framework/2.3.1
```

In my case, I used Restlet 2.3.1 with the Jetty extension for the client connector (to actually send the request).

If you set a value on the client side, as described below:

```
String url = "http://localhost:8182/contacts/";
ClientResource cr = new ClientResource(url);
cr.getClientInfo().setAgent("My user agent");
cr.get();
```

You will get now this value on the server side:

```
Jetty/9.2.6.v20141205,My user agent
```

Hope it helps you,
Thierry